Sobolev space on the circle
I'm styudying Sobolev space on the circle. The Sobolev space is $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{S}^1)=\left\{u\in L^p(\mathbb{S}^1)\colon \left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+k^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(k)\right)\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{S}^1)}<\infty\right\}$
Fact: If $s>n/p$, then $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Question. If $s>1/p$. Is  $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{S}^1)\subset C(\mathbb{S}^1)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ valid too?.
